# python twython tweet extraction

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using twython to connect to Twitter API and retrieve a query. Here is an example of what I get:

```
---START----

{u'next_page': u'?page=2&max_id=215397707'
....
: 215397707794219008L, u'page': 1}

----END----
```

What I am interested in is the actual tweet which starts like this:

```
u'text': u'@ilariargn devi fare un corso sul respiro! Sarebbero 7686879 euro, ci vieni? #perderetempo', u'from_user_name':
```

So everything between "u'text': u'" and "u'from_user_name'". I tried to get this information first with key and value because it is a dictionary. Does not work. Then I tried to convert the dictionary into a list and use a string search to get the position. Does not work either. How do I get this information?

I tried suggested solutions and received following messages:

```
tweet = json.loads(results)[u'text']
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

And for the second solution - if I write [t'text] I get a syntax error:

```
tweet = results[u'text']
KeyError: u'text'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. After some trials I found the following solution to access the actual tweets:

```
counter = 1
for key, value in results.iteritems():
    if key == "results":
        svalue = str(value)
        while counter != -1:
            tweetposstart = svalue.find("u'text'",counter)
            tweetposend = svalue.find("u'from_user_name'",counter)
            if tweetposstart != -1:
                tweet = svalue[tweetposstart:tweetposend]
                print tweet
                counter = counter + tweetposstart
            else:
                counter = tweetposstart
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get is a json object:

```
import json
tweet = json.loads(whatyouget)[u'text']
```

Or, if you get the dic already parsed, then:

```
tweet = whatyouget[t'text']
```

Comment: Hi, Thx for you comments but it does not work. I will post the error messages in my question.